Use Web localStorage in Objective-C but not working
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import <OneSignalFramework/OneSignalFramework.h> // Import OneSignalFramework

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    
    // Remove this method to stop OneSignal Debugging
    [OneSignal.Debug setLogLevel:ONE_S_LL_VERBOSE];
    
    // OneSignal initialization
    [OneSignal initialize:@"OneSignal App ID" withLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
    
    // requestPermission will show the native iOS notification permission prompt.
    // We recommend removing the following code and instead using an In-App Message to prompt for notification permission
    [OneSignal.Notifications requestPermission:^(BOOL accepted) {
        NSLog(@"User accepted notifications: %d", accepted);
    } fallbackToSettings:true];
    
//    NSString *userId = OneSignal.User.onesignalId;
    // Store OneSignal player ID in local storage
    NSString *oneSignalPlayerID = OneSignal.User.onesignalId;
    if (oneSignalPlayerID != nil) {
        NSLog(@"OneSignal Player ID: %@", oneSignalPlayerID);
        // Store the player ID in local storage (NSUserDefaults)
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:oneSignalPlayerID forKey:@"oneSignalPlayerID"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        
    } else {
        NSLog(@"OneSignal Player ID is nil or not available.");
    }
    
    // Retrieve the value from NSUserDefaults
    NSString *playerID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"oneSignalPlayerID"];

    // Log the value
    NSLog(@"oneSignalPlayerID: %@", playerID);

    // Login your customer with externalId
    // [OneSignal login:@"EXTERNAL_ID"];
    
    return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

@end



used this method but having error in webView "Use of undeclared identifier 'webView'"
NSString \*oneSignalPlayerID = OneSignal.User.onesignalId;
if (oneSignalPlayerID != nil) {
NSLog(@"OneSignal Player ID: %@", oneSignalPlayerID);

        // Inject JavaScript to store the player ID in localStorage
        NSString *jsCode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"localStorage.setItem('OneSignalPlayerID', '%@');", oneSignalPlayerID];
        [self.webView evaluateJavaScript:jsCode completionHandler:nil];
        
    } else {
        NSLog(@"OneSignal Player ID is nil or not available.");
    }

However, when I try to compile/run this code, I'm getting the error message: "Use of undeclared identifier 'webView'". It seems like webView is not recognized or declared anywhere in my codebase.
Can someone please guide me on how to properly declare or access webView in my code? I want to store onesignalPlayerID to web localStorage using webView.

You have self.webView which means that the class that the code is in must have a property named webView. The error indicates that you do not.

Don’t know how to implement this.  This is compiled code of Ionic for iOS APP and i am using iOS onsignal sdk in Xcode

Thanks for help. Just added the property and problem resolved..
